# jquery window.innerWidth remove and replace content

Tags: jquery, media-queries, responsive-design

I'm building a responsive site but don't want to just *hide* elements for smaller screens, I want to **remove** them completely to reduce load times.

I've got this working so far with

```
if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
    $('.widescreen').remove();
}
```

The class `.widescreen` is added to all elements that are only to be loaded on screens wider than 768px

I then want this to work if a user resizes the browser window (or turns a device 90°) so I tried this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    //small-screen
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
        $('.widescreen').remove();
    }
    //end small-screen
});
```

Which works but only when a window is resized not loaded at the smaller size. Which I guessed would happen.

Is there a way of achieving this so it works both when a page is loaded and when the browser window is resized?

Then, of course, the trick is to **add the content back** when the window is resized to wider than 768px! But I'll try to figure that one out if the first part is actually possible!!

Comment: Have you managed to solve it yet?

Comment: No, I'm just using media queries to hide the content. Not ideal but maybe at a later stage someone will figure out a good way to NOT load content based on a media query. I'm now working on adding/removing classes with @abuduba's `$(window).resize` method below for another purpose.

Answer (score 6):

```
$(function() {   
 $(window).resize(function() {
        //small-screen
        if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
            $('.widescreen').remove();
        }
        //end small-screen
    }) .resize(); // trigger resize event

})
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! If I place this in the head of my page am I right in assuming it will remove the elements before they have loaded – jus want to make sure load times and page sizes are kept to an absolute minimum on mobile devices.

Comment: If you put that code in function to `ready` event ( either document.ready(fn) or  $(fn) ) - like in my solution function will be triggered when document is loaded

Answer (score 1):

why not putting the code that check the size on a function, calling this function when load and also when resize.

```
function checkSize() {
    //small-screen
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
        $('.widescreen').remove();
    }
    //end small-screen
}

checkSize();

$(window).resize(function() {
    checkSize();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use media queries to hide those parts.

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  .widescreen { display: none; }
}
```

If you´d like to use JavaScript then this does about the same thing;

```
$(function() {   
 $(window).resize(function() {
     $('.widescreen').toggle( window.innerWidth >= 768 )
  }) .resize();
});
```

I don´t see the point of removing the elements instead of just hiding them as in both cases the client still have to download the HTML.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to make sure content is NOT loaded for small devices, not sure if this is even possible...

Comment: That can only be done server side, before the response (content) is sent to the client. The problem is then that it´s not possible (very hard) to know the screen resolution/window size server side.

Comment: It´s possible to detect mobile devices and then modify the content or redirect to the mobile site but this doesn´t seem to be what you´re looking for.

Comment: thanks, that helps clear things up. I might look into loading content dynamically when above a certain width.

Comment: That could be one way to solve it but it´s not to recommend for the purpose of toggling content on tilt. Have I answered your question now? :)